# AForge FileVideoSource class video file issue

Tags: c#, aforge

I am experiencing some issue with FileVideoSource class within AForge nuget.
I am currently able to capture the vision from my laptop camera and detect motion on it.
Now I would like to do the same, but using a video from file, but I am not able to even access the video and show it.

I have the following code:

```
...
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // var existTest = File.Exists("test.avi");
   var videoFile = new FileVideoSource("test.avi");
   videoFile.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
   videoFile.Start();
}

private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
   var img = eventArgs.Frame;
   pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

After debugging I ensured myself that file was found (checked with File.Exists() method) but after that literally nothing is happening. I tried to set breakpoint inside the video_NewFrame FrameEventHandler and it is never reached.

I've also tried the .mpg file instead of .avi. The same situation. I can play both video files with WMP so I think it is not a codec issue. Both video files are stored in my output Debug folder.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Turns out, codecs were the culprit. Try downloading them from https://www.codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_mega.htm

My first step (well not quite first :) ) was capturing video errors:

```
fileVideo.VideoSourceError += new VideoSourceErrorEventHandler(videoSource_Error);
```

and

```
        private void videoSource_Error(object sender, VideoSourceErrorEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.Description);
        }
```

I got "Did not find acceptable output video pin in the given source", then I installed the codecs and the video is now playing.